# What does MySingleTon st = MySingleTon.getInstance(); mean in this code?

Tags: java

Today I was reading a sample java program to create a singleton class. The code is as follows:

```
public class MySingleTon {

private static MySingleTon myObj;
/**
 * Create private constructor
 */
private MySingleTon(){

}
/**
 * Create a static method to get instance.
 */
public static MySingleTon getInstance(){
    if(myObj == null){
        myObj = new MySingleTon();
    }
    return myObj;
}

public void getSomeThing(){
    // do something here
    System.out.println("I am here....");
}

public static void main(String a[]){
    MySingleTon st = MySingleTon.getInstance();
    st.getSomeThing();
}
}
```

I don't understand what the piece of code `MySingleTon st = MySingleTon.getInstance();` means? 
I mean we are creating an object `st` by `MySingleTon st`; so it should have been written as `new MySingleton`. So what is `MySingleTon.getInstance();` doing actually?

Comment: Google "singleton pattern".  It is, depending on your point of view, a "pattern" or an "anti-pattern" that is all the rage for the past 2-3 years.

Comment: Bad singleton example: not thread safe!

Comment: The point the sample program is trying to make would have been clearer if `main()` were a member of a different class. Then Java's access rules would prevent `main()` from invoking `new MySingleton()` at all (hence clarifying the need for `MySingleTon.getInstance()`). (I also cannot fathom why the `T` is capitalized in `MySingleTon`. It's not supposed to be camel case for "my single ton".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so it should have been written as new MySingleton.

The instance is still being created using `new` only, if only you've noticed the `getInstance()` method.

> So what is MySingleTon.getInstance(); doing actually?

It invokes the `getInstance()` method which is a `static` method of `MySingleton` class. That method returns a new instance or an existing instance if it is already there, of `MySingleton` class. Basically, `getInstance()` is a factory method.

This is how a singleton pattern is implemented. If you use `new` keyword to create an instance of a Singleton class, then you can create as many instances as you wanted, which makes that class non-singleton. And that is the reason why the constructor of the class is `private`. You might be able to invoke the constructor currently, as your `main` method is in that class only. Try moving the `main()` method to a different class, and then it would be more clear.

Now coming to some issue with that singleton. You should not really implement a singleton that way. For one, it is not thread safe. Secondly, it is not serialization safe. In the sense, when you serialize and deserialize it's instance, a new instance will be created. Ideally, you should avoid using Singleton completely, as it's evil. But whenever you do, the best way to implement singleton pattern is using an `enum`:

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this follows the singleton pattern, which means you only instance the object only once.

Which means:

1. You have private variable to hold the class instace.
2. You don't use the constructor to create the instance but use the static method to initialize the instance.
3. Inside getInstance you first check if the instance is already initialized or not. if is return it.

Read more at wikipedia gives you more details about the pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 1):

This is the Singleton Pattern.

It does not allow you to contruct a `new MySingleton` since the constructor is private. This pattern ensures, that you can *not* create more than one Instance of this class, but always retrieve a prior generated instance by calling `getInstance()`.

The instance is stored as a `static` variable which means: One time constructed, it will exist until the Application is closed.

It is commonly used to store application configuration properties you need to access over and over again.

Comment: Except the sample program is confusing to OP: since `main()` is a member of `MySingleton`, the constructor is accessible from `main()` and multiple calls to `new MySingleton()` are allowed.

Comment: @TedHopp True. That of course destroyes the Idea behind a private Constructor!

Comment: Yep. If the sample program was supposed to be for pedagogical purposes, it's a very poor job.

Answer (score 1):

`getInstance()` does not always create a new object.  `myObj` is a `static` member that belongs to the entire class, not to each "instance" of `MySingleTon`.  Therefore, the first time `getInstance()` is called, since `myObj` is `null`, a new instance is created.  But the second and subsequent times, `myObj` will not be null, and therefore `getInstance` returns a reference to the object that was previously.  The effect is that only one instance of `MySingleTon` is ever created.

A program cannot call `new MySingleTon()` because the constructor has been declared `private`, which makes it invisible outside the `MySingleTon` class.

(P.S. "singleton" is one word, so spelling it `SingleTon` is really incorrect, unless you're planning on writing a class with 2,000 pounds of code :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the point of the sample program is obscured because `main()` is a member of `MySingleTon`, so it can, indeed, call `new SingleTon()`. (P.S. Perhaps it's 2,200 pounds of code if it's a metric ton. :))